# Should I set up a protocol for Objective C array objects to avoid a compiler warning?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsarray, protocols

I have a class, let's call it ABC, with an NSArray *objects property, and the objects in the NSArray can be one of two different classes, X and Y.  Both X and Y have a **path** property, but the compiler doesn't know this.

Therefore, even though ABC will always find the **path** property on my array objects, I get compiler warnings on my code -- "No 'path' method found".  App runs fine but I'm getting annoyed by the warnings.  How can I fix my code (with protocols?) so that the compiler stops complaining?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import some header that declares a `path` method. When it's compiling your code, the compiler looks at the list of methods this file knows about and it sees that there is no `path` method. You just need to tell it that the method exists and its signature is whatever and the compiler will be satisfied. No protocol is necessary.

Comment: When you do `objectAtIndex`, `NSArray` returns object with `id` type, so compiler can't know about methods in your class.

Comment: @beefon: You're partly right, but that doesn't change what I'm saying. The compiler does not know the class of the object, but it does know what methods it has seen in *any* class. If no visible class has declared a method, the compiler will tell you it hasn't seen any method that corresponds to the message you're sending, which is the warning that the OP saw.

Comment: I'm confused -- both my class X (an NSManagedObject class) and my class Y (an NSObject subclass) have the path property declared in the header.  Yet I was still getting the warning -- I think for the reason beefon adduces, that the compiler sees [objects objectAtIndex:0] as an id.

Comment: @Elon: An object typed as `id` can be sent any known message without a warning. That's the whole point of using `id` versus a static type. It will only warn if no currently visible class implements the method. Are you importing those classes' headers in the file where the warning is occurring?

Comment: Aha, that was it.  Wasn't importing the headers.  This seems like the cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2):

Do both X and Y derive from the same super class that contains "path"? If "path" is conceptually the same value AND X and Y are related by this value, then it should either be in a super class or protocol.

Additionally you can use `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol to directly access values by string via `- (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key`. You do lose any type safety using this method, however.

Comment: I suppose they could, but in my case they don't.  One is actually a CoreData managed object class and the other is a special-purpose class (dynamic images vs. static images).

Answer (score 1):

```
valueForKey:@"path"
```

Comment: Brilliant, this worked great.  I'm not sure why?  But it did.

Comment: This is not brilliant - see Chuck's answer.  It's using a very dynamic string-based way to access the method.  It's sufficiently dynamic that the compiler is unable to warn for anything.  If I saw this in code I was reading, I would be on guard that the author wasn't very experienced and was willing to get things to work by flailing.

Comment: Why not brilliant? I think KVC is very brilliant way to get things working in very beautiful way.

Comment: I think the reason it would be viewed as "not brilliant" is because it unnecessarily works around the language's error-checking. Purposely making your code more error-prone could be viewed as a bad thing. I don't personally mind it so much, but I don't think it's the best solution either.